# How to generate this matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

[image]

H matrix is n-by-n, n=10000. I can use loop to generate this matrix in matlab. I just wonder if there are any methods that can do this without looping in matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that the upper right portion of the matrix consists of `1 / sqrt(n*(n-1))`, the diagonal elements consist of `-(n-1)/sqrt(n*(n-1))`, the first column consists of `1/sqrt(n)` and the rest of the elements are zero.

We can generate the full matrix that consists of the first column having all `1 / sqrt(n)`, then having the rest of the columns with `1 / sqrt(n*(n-1))` then we'll need to modify the matrix to include the rest of what you want.

As such, let's concentrate on the elements that start from row 2, column 2 as these follow a pattern.  Once we're done, we can construct the other things that build up the final matrix.

```
x = 2:n;
Hsmall = repmat([1./sqrt(x.*(x-1))], n-1, 1);
```

Next, we will tackle the diagonal elements:

```
Hsmall(logical(eye(n-1))) = -(x-1)./sqrt(x.*(x-1));
```

Now, let's zero the rest of the elements:

```
Hsmall(tril(logical(ones(n-1)),-1)) = 0;
```

Now that we're done, let's create a new matrix that pieces all of this together:

```
H = [1/sqrt(n) 1./sqrt(x.*(x-1)); repmat(1/sqrt(n), n-1, 1) Hsmall];
```

Therefore, the full code is:

```
x = 2:n;
Hsmall = repmat([1./sqrt(x.*(x-1))], n-1, 1);
Hsmall(logical(eye(n-1))) = -(x-1)./sqrt(x.*(x-1));
Hsmall(tril(logical(ones(n-1)),-1)) = 0;
H = [1/sqrt(n) 1./sqrt(x.*(x-1)); repmat(1/sqrt(n), n-1, 1) Hsmall];
```

Here's an example with `n = 6`:

```
>> H

H =

  Columns 1 through 3

         0.408248290463863         0.707106781186547         0.408248290463863
         0.408248290463863        -0.707106781186547         0.408248290463863
         0.408248290463863                         0        -0.816496580927726
         0.408248290463863                         0                         0
         0.408248290463863                         0                         0
         0.408248290463863                         0                         0

  Columns 4 through 6

         0.288675134594813         0.223606797749979         0.182574185835055
         0.288675134594813         0.223606797749979         0.182574185835055
         0.288675134594813         0.223606797749979         0.182574185835055
        -0.866025403784439         0.223606797749979         0.182574185835055
                         0        -0.894427190999916         0.182574185835055
                         0                         0        -0.912870929175277
```

Comment: @meng - Glad I could help!   Interesting problem this was.

Comment: Good explanation on this, as always! Would have gone with triu + repmat myself, so had to look for alternate methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with a pretty large `n` value of `10000`, you might want to squeeze out as much performance as possible.
Going with that, you can use an efficient approach based on [`cumsum`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) -

```
%// Values to be set in each column for the upper triangular region
upper_tri = 1./sqrt([1:n].*(0:n-1));

%// Diagonal indices
diag_idx = [1:n+1:n*n];

%// Setup output array
out = zeros(n,n);

%// Set the first row of output array with upper triangular values
out(1,:) = upper_tri;

%// Set the diagonal elements with the negative triangular values.
%// The intention here is to  perform CUMSUM across each column later on,
%// thus therewould be zeros beyond the diagonal positions for each column
out(diag_idx) = -upper_tri;

%// Set the first element of output array with n^(-1/2)
out(1) = -1/sqrt(n);

%// Finally, perform CUMSUM as suggested earlier
out = cumsum(out,1);

%// Set the diagonal elements with the actually expected values
out(diag_idx(2:end)) = upper_tri(2:end).*[-1:-1:-(n-1)];
```

---

**Runtime Tests**

(I) With `n = 10000`, the runtime at my end were - `Elapsed time is 0.457543 seconds`.

(II) Now, as the final performance-squeezing practice, you can edit the pre-allocation step for `out` with a faster pre-allocation scheme as listed in this [MATLAB Undodumented Blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance). Thus, the pre-allocation step would look like this -

```
out(n,n) = 0;
```

The runtime with this edited code was - `Elapsed time is 0.400399 seconds`.

(III) The runtime for `n = 10000` with the [other answer by @rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594604/3293881) yielded - `Elapsed time is 1.306339 seconds.`

Comment: Leave it to you to always blow my implementations out of the water with speed :). +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Though your explanations are the best!! And you have come a long way on the optimizations part, specially with the bsxfun, unique, accumarray and such!